# Email verification on area51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, email-verification

If you enter a previously verified address in your profile, it asks you again to verify it.

I know a user may not be changing his email address a lot, but I was playing a little with different gravatars, until I decided on one which was already verified. I had to verify it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't retain a history of previously verified emails per account, so it's impractical to implement this at this time.